# Bring nohup job to foreground

Tags: command-line, process, background-process, nohup

Consider the following [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) execution:

```
nohup script.sh > script.out &
```

Is there a way to log off the terminal, reconnect, bring the process back to foreground and interact with it using the keyboard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wanted to start a script, have it run without the output bothering your terminal and then bring it up later to interact with it, you might want to take a look at a terminal multiplexer. Depending on your system I would recommend `tmux` or `screen`. You can find some info on how to use them in the links below:

tmux:

- [A Tmux Primer](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tmux/)
- [A Quick and Easy Guide to tmux](http://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/)
- [Tmux Cheat Sheet & Quick Reference](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/)

screen:

- [Screen - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen)
- [GNU Screen: an introduction and beginner's tutorial](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935)
- [screen keyboard shortcuts](http://www.pixelbeat.org/lkdb/screen.html)

*edit: added links for tmux primers*

Comment: +1 Excellent tool I didn't know of. Many thanks.

Comment: I would recommend `byobu` as a very nice addition to `tmux`

Answer (score 33):

[**nohup**](http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html) does not disconnect a command from terminal, it makes your script ignore [`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP), and redirects `stdout/stderr` to a file `nohup.out`, so that the command can continue running in the background after you log out.

`nohup` does not automatically put the command it runs in the background. One must do that explicitly, by ending the command line with an `&`.

```
$ nohup ./script.sh &
[1] 3390
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
```

[`jobs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/jobs.1) can print currently running jobs and their status. If the command `jobs` cannot find it, then it is no longer a [child process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) of that shell.

```
$ jobs 
[1]+  Running                 nohup ./script.sh &
```

One can be bring back a background job to foreground in bash using `fg` even if it is run with `nohup`. But that won't change the **output redirection, which will still be going to the file `nohup.out`**.

```
$ fg
nohup ./script.sh
```

If you close the shell/terminal or log off, your command is no longer a child of that shell. It belongs to [`init`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) process. If you search in `pstree` you'll see it is now owned by process 1 (`init`). That cannot be brought back to the foreground because the foreground no longer exists.

Comment: `If the command jobs cannot find it, then it is no longer a child process of that shell.` This is wrong: try this sequence to see how: `sleep 100 & disown ; echo Jobs:; jobs; echo Tree:; pstree -ap $$`. After this command you'll still see `sleep` work with the same PID printed out when you spawned it, while `jobs` will print nothing. The only way a child process can stop being child is losing its parent (then the orphan becomes the child of `init`) or forking+exiting (but then the PID changes, so it's not the original child).

Answer (score 5):

I'll second the use of a terminal multiplexer, but [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), not screen. Screen is, for all intents and purposes, unmaintained. Its configuration is a dark art, likely first recorded in an appendix of the Necronomicon. Attempting to write your own config is as a glimpse of Cthulu. Seriously. Look around at people's [.screenrc files](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=screenrc). To be sure, there are ways to mediate screen's abomination of a config flle. [Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) does an admirable job as the veil between mortal users and unholy code. It comes with sensible colours, a menu interface, and perhaps most importantly, a status bar.

But as I said, I recommend [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) instead. It still requires some minor configuration,  but it is [well documented](http://man.cx/tmux), and your config file won't look like gibberish. Also, you start out with colours and a status bar. Compare my screenrc and tmux.conf files:

- [screenrc](https://github.com/djeikyb/dot-files/blob/master/.screenrc)
- [tmux.conf](https://github.com/djeikyb/dot-files/blob/master/.tmux.conf)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interested in looking live hat the output this might suit you:

```
nohup script.sh 2>&1 script.out &
# later:
tail -f script.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Any Linux command can be sent to the background with '`&`' appended at the last.

To view all the background jobs, you can issue `jobs`

```
jobs
[1]  + suspended  nohup sh zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties
[2]    running    nohup sh kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
[3]  - running    nohup sudo mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
```

Here I am running 3 jobs in background: zookeeper, kafka and mongo daemon.
[1],[2] and [3] are respective job numbers for these tasks.

You can bring those task to foreground using `fg %$taskNumber.`